# AMP images in readers

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-img

I have a website with AMP pages that allow editors to add images to the page.  The images are displayed using an amp-img element and render in any normal browser.

When either user a reader view or being crawled by a site such as Embedly the amp-img elements are not displayed.

I assume this is caused by the amp-img element not being a valid HTML element so is ignored.  Is there anyway to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a noscript element for renderers not using javascript:

```
<amp-img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome" height="400" width="800">
  <noscript>
    <img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome" height="400" width="800" />
  </noscript>
</amp-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had left out the head tag of `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>` as listed in the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#required-markup). Including that fixed it.